# Where to add Auth session variables when the user is logging in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I’d like to add session variable to Auth when the user logs in.

Where should that code be exactly?

Here’s my structure:

Group table (parent table):

```
Id  
Currency
Client_type
```

User table (child table):

```
Id
Group_Id (FK)
Name
```

I’d like for the values of `Currency` and `Client_type` to be available globally in Auth.

Thanks, using Laravel 5.2

Comment: How is "*User table (child table)*" related to `users` table?

Comment: The User table is related to the Group table, not users table.. not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Auth::user()` will have the logged in user object from which you should be able to access all its properties.

edit: if the currency is a property of a related model then you should have your relations set up, maybe something like this in the `User` model:

```
public function group()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Group::class,'Group_Id');
}
```

and you access it then like so

```
Auth::user()->group->Currency;
```

BTW I'm not sure how the tables are related.

Comment: Super thanks! but where (in which function) should that code be if I want it executed when the user is logging in?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you don't need to do anything to have it ready, meaning whenever you need to access a user property (and the user is indeed authenticated)  you simply access it `Auth::user()->anyProperty;`

Comment: Yes, with the default Laravel, Auth::user() is available from everywhere. In my app, i've added a parent table (groups) over the default users table, so I'd like to add session variables (taken from my groups table) to Auth. Currency is not a column from the users table, but its from the groups table, and the groups table is not part of Auth by default.

Comment: OMG, I was trying to reinvent the wheel. Didn't know I could access group values directly with Auth. Thanks so much @khaliddabjan